# Why doesn't Bash overwrite my array with a new one?

Tags: arrays, bash, overwrite

I stripped my use case to these 3 lines (plus the output):

```
A=(foo bar)
A=$(echo "spam egg")
echo ${A[@]}
spam egg bar
```

It creates an array with two element written by hand. Then some time later I want to replace my array with the output from a command line tool (e.g. `ls *.vhd`). Instead of replacing the array, Bash only replaces the first element, so bar gets "attached" at the end.

If I use another handwritten array, then I can't reproduce this behavior.

```
A=(foo bar)
A=(spam egg)
echo ${A[@]}
spam egg
```

So I suspect it's related to using `$()`. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: `A=$(echo "spam egg")` is equivalent to `A[0]=$(echo "spam egg")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parentheses in the assignment, so that it is treated as an array, rather than **one** long string with spaces:

```
A=$(echo "spam egg")
echo ${A[0]}
```

-> `spam egg`

```
A=($(echo "spam egg"))
echo ${A[0]}
```

-> `spam`

(The parentheses for `$()` that tell bash to run a command don't also count for telling it to collect the result as an array.)

Comment: Indexing does not work on regular strings. `${A[1]}` would not be `s` in your first example.

Comment: Ah, sorry!  I wrote the examples in `zsh`, though the main point of needing parens still stands. Change to: `A=($(echo "spam egg")); echo ${A[0]} -> spam` for `bash`

Comment: It would be nice to update your answer to show relevant `bash` code.

Comment: Thanks. I've spent half of the day debugging this ...